# How can I avoid checking if a tic-tac-toe game is over in this Java bool method not to hardcode every possible case?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, methods, boolean, tic-tac-toe

'Cos maybe it's easy for 3x3 but not 5x5

```
private static boolean gameOver(char[][] arr, int row, int col){
    if((arr[0][0]=='X' && arr[0][1]=='X' && arr[0][2]=='X')||
       (arr[1][0]=='X' && arr[1][1]=='X' && arr[1][2]=='X')||
       (arr[2][0]=='X' && arr[2][1]=='X' && arr[2][2]=='X')||
       (arr[0][0]=='X' && arr[1][0]=='X' && arr[2][0]=='X')||
       (arr[0][1]=='X' && arr[1][1]=='X' && arr[2][1]=='X')||
       (arr[0][2]=='X' && arr[1][2]=='X' && arr[2][2]=='X')||
       (arr[0][0]=='X' && arr[1][1]=='X' && arr[2][2]=='X')||
       (arr[0][2]=='X' && arr[1][1]=='X' && arr[2][0]=='X')
       ){
           System.out.println("X wins!");
           return true;
       }
    else if((arr[0][0]=='O' && arr[0][1]=='O' && arr[0][2]=='O')||
       (arr[1][0]=='O' && arr[1][1]=='O' && arr[1][2]=='O')||
       (arr[2][0]=='O' && arr[2][1]=='O' && arr[2][2]=='O')||
       (arr[0][0]=='O' && arr[1][0]=='O' && arr[2][0]=='O')||
       (arr[0][1]=='O' && arr[1][1]=='O' && arr[2][1]=='O')||
       (arr[0][2]=='O' && arr[1][2]=='O' && arr[2][2]=='O')||
       (arr[0][0]=='O' && arr[1][1]=='O' && arr[2][2]=='O')||
       (arr[0][2]=='O' && arr[1][1]=='O' && arr[2][0]=='O')
       ){
           System.out.println("O wins!");
           return true;
       }
    else if(arr[0][0]!='_' && arr[0][1]!='_' && arr[0][2]!='_'
    && arr[1][0]!='_' && arr[1][1]!='_' && arr[1][2]!='_'
    && arr[2][0]!='_' && arr[2][1]!='_' && arr[2][2]!='_'){
        System.out.println("Draw!");
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

Is there some nested for loop that will help?
Or some specific algorithm?
(Method returns true if the game is over no matter if there is a winner or not)

Comment: game is over when a) any gamer build line on X, Y, or diagonal b) table is full. Two logically clear conditions. Use methods

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need nested loops, just ordinary loops for the win condition:

- loop across rows and look for a row with all 'X's or all 'O's
- loop across columns and look for a row with all 'X's or all 'O's
- check both diagonals (no loop needed here) for all 'X's or all 'O's

You only need nested loop for draw check.

---

Now if you wanted a more sophisticated solution, you could:

- Keep track of number of free cells (start at 9, and if you reach 0 without finding a win, it's a draw)
- Only check row, column where the last 'X' or 'O' was added (and possibly diagonals)